Facebook Chat Button Is not working in nextjs
I am using react-facebook package to show facebook chat button to one of my nextjs application. It was working fine. but suddenly last few days it's not working as expected.
This is my code:
'use client'
import { FacebookProvider, CustomChat } from 'react-facebook';


  function FacebookChat({appId, pageId, themeColor}) {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId={appId} chatSupport>
        <CustomChat themeColor={themeColor} pageId={pageId} minimized={true}/>
      </FacebookProvider>  
    );
  }
  
  export default FacebookChat;

I followed these steps to setup facebook chat button:
1. Get Page ID: Go to your page -> About -> Page transparency and Copy the Page ID

2. Get APP ID: Go to https://developers.facebook.com -> My Apps -> Create App -> Select Other -> Next -> Select Consumer -> Give an app name -> Create App -> verify by fb password -> Go to App Settings -> Basic -> Fill up all info -> Turn on App Mode to live -> and Copy the App ID

3. Whitelist your domain: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=advanced_messaging -> Make sure you selected the page -> Add your domain to Whitelisted domains

How to resolve this?

Here is the message from meta

Chat Plugin is going away soon.
On 9 May 2024, you will no longer be able to access any
functionalities of Chat Plugin. Effective immediately, Chat Plugin in
guest mode is no longer available. Other features such as m.me links
will still be available for you to use.

here is the link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/
